# How to display all examples with the highest error keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, dataset, theano

I use keras to train my neural network. My error on the testing set is about 80%. Is there a possibility to find what examples are evaluated with error?

How can I find the interval which is evaluated with errors if I use time-series data?

Comment: You have predictions and you have original values, you can directly compare and check which are wrong. You can write interval analysis or anything else you want on top of it.

Comment: So, keras have no built-in function to do this?